Missing few changes returned by 'onCellsChanged' function in ReactGrid component
Description:
I am using ReactGrid component from https://reactgrid.com/support. It is accepting onCellsChanged prop that supposed to return all the changes of the cells with CellChange imterface .
However, when I am copying data from one row to another, it is not returning all the necessary changes especially custom-checkbox cells (we have used the same code that is mentioned in the library's github repo for checkbox - https://github.com/silevis/reactgrid/blob/develop/src/lib/CellTemplates/CheckboxCellTemplate.tsx).
But when we paste the same copied data to the same row for the second time, then it is returning all the data. Please check the attached screenshot for more clarity.
Current behaviour:
When we copied one row and try to paste it to another row, then onCellsChanged function is not returning all the data, but on second time paste, it is returning. Please check the screenshot attached. When I tried to paste the data for the first time, library is returning changes that is print in the console using 'changes' keyword. And notice the second time 'changes' printed in the console for the second time paste.
Console of the changes for the first and second time
Expected:
onCellsChanged function should return all the cell changes for the first time.
